# Overflow in C++

Tags: c++, overflow

So..

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long i,y,n,x=45;
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;

    for(n = 0; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        y = (pow(-1,n)*pow(x,2*n)) / factorial;
        cout << "COS IS " << y << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
    {
        factorial *= 2*i;
    }

}
```

I get an overflow but I really don't know why. I use unsigned long long just to make sure that I on't get but.. I still get it. Even limited to small numbers. I tried to implement this:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Power_Series_for_Cosine_and_Sine

But I really can't do it because of the overflow. Do you have any ideea on what can I do ? I am newbie in programming so, take it easy on me :D

Comment: Please post your code int the question and not as external link

Comment: Use `double` instead of `long long`. But your algorithm is wrong anyway.

Comment: Oh, and BTW, the formula you need to use radians and not degrées.

Comment: 45^32 is 79946681398258369524447459012293256819248199462890625. It is 176 binary digits long.

Comment: I did put a link to it because stack wanted to reformat the code and I did't have the patience to do it. What's wrong with the algorithm ?

Comment: @MaximilianHartung Consider the value of `factorial` during the first loop.

Comment: @MaximilianHartung you should learn how to format code whan aksing questions on stackoverflow, it takes 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues.

1. you use integer types when you should use floating point types
2. you use unsigned types for signed calculations
3. you don't use radians but degrees (45° ≈ 0.78539 radians)
4. you don't calculate the factorial in the loop, it is always 1, you only calculate it at the end of the loop but then it's too late, and your calculation of the factorial is wrong anyway.
5. the algorithm is wrong, it just doesn't do what Maclaurin's therorem says, you need to sum up the terms, but you just print the terms.

You probably want this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

long factorial(int n)
{
  long result = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    result *= i;
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  double x = 0.785398163397448309616;  //PI/4 expectd result COS(PI/4) = 0.7071067

  double mycosinus = 0;
  for (int n = 0; n <= 5; n++)
  {
    mycosinus += (pow(-1, n) * pow(x, 2 * n)) / factorial(2*n);
    cout << "COS IS " << mycosinus << endl;
  }
}
```

This is your wrong algorithm for calculating the factorial of 5:

```
int main()
{
  int n = 5;
  int factorial = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    factorial *= 2 * i;
  }

  cout << "factorial 5 = " << factorial << endl;
}
```

The calculated value is 3840 instead of 120. I let you find out what's wrong yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For performing this sort of maths you need to use a floating point like `float` or `double` not integral types like `long`, `int` or `long long`, given that sin and cos can both return negative numbers you shouldn't be using `unsigned` either.